ng2-pdf-viewer shows valunerability in angular 17
ng2-pdf-viewer shows valunerability in angular 17.how do resolve this.
I have tried with npm audit fix.this will shows again valunerability .how do resolve. can we  continue with this  or will receive any potential issues in future?
